# thumbnail codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Montei essa classe que faz um *multiupload* de imagens, cria as pastas de acordo com o id_ano, e em seguida, gera os *thumbs* dessas imagens conforme o `foreach` roda. O problema é que os *thumbs* não estão sendo gerados.

Minha classe thumb:

```
function _createThumbnail($filename,$path)
{        

    $config['image_library']    = "gd2";      

    $config['source_image']     = "{$path}/{$filename}";                

    $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;      

    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;      

    $config['width'] = "80";      

    $config['height'] = "80";

    $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
    //die(print_r($this->image_lib->resize()));
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())

    {

        die(print_r($this->image_lib->display_errors()));

    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.
Eu usaria da seguinte forma:

```
function _createThumbnail($filename,$path)
{        
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library']    = "gd2";      

    $config['source_image']     = "{$path}/{$filename}";                

    $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;      

    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;      

    $config['width'] = "80";      

    $config['height'] = "80";

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    //die(print_r($this->image_lib->resize()));
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())

    {

        die(print_r($this->image_lib->display_errors()));

    }      
}
```

Já tive problemas em servidores em que primeiro eu devo limpar a configuração da lib e depois configurar ela novamente.

Espero ter ajudado.

Oss